# qMenuSystem using DigoleSerial library doesn’t work on my I2C Monochrome OLED

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c, lcd

Just like the title says I’m trying to make qMenuSystem to work with my oled display. 
Here is what I know so far about my display :

```
- It's a Monochrome OLED 128x64 (Blue) Display
- It's connecting using I2C using the 0x3C address allocated 
- It's working well with Adafruit SSD1306 and Adafruit GFX Libraries 
- It's looking like this : https://cdn3.volusion.com/btfzd.umflq/v/vspfiles/photos/AD304-2T.jpg?1526038845
```

The library DigoleSerial has the following files :

```
//DigoleSerial.cpp


//Digole Digital Solutions: www.digole.com
#include "DigoleSerial.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include "Arduino.h"

/*
// Communication set up command
 * "SB":Baud (ascII bytes end with 0x00/0x0A/0x0D) -- set UART Baud Rate
 * "SI2CA":Address(1 byte <127) -- Set I2C address, default address is:0x27
 * "DC":1/0(1byte) -- set config display on/off, if set to 1, displayer will display current commucation setting when power on
// Text Function command
 * "CL": -- Clear screen--OK
 * "CS":1/0 (1 byte)-- Cursor on/off
 * "TP":x(1 byte) y(1 byte) -- set text position
 * "TT":string(bytes) end with 0x00/0x0A/0x0D -- display string under regular mode
// Graphic function command
 * "GP":x(1byte) y(1byte) -- set current graphic position
 * "DM":"C/!/~/&/|/^"(ASCII 1byte) -- set drawing mode--C="Copy",! and ~ = "Not", & = "And", | = "Or", ^ = "Xor"
 * "SC":1/0 (1byte) -- set draw color--only 1 and 0
 * "LN":x0(1byte) y0(1byte) x1(1byte) y2(1byte)--draw line from x0,y0 to x1,y1,set new pot to x1,y1
 * "LT":x(1byte) y(1byte) -- draw line from current pos to x,y
 * "CC":x(1byte) y(1byte) ratio(byte) -- draw circle at x,y with ratio
 * "DP":x(1byte) y(1byte) Color(1byte) -- draw a pixel--OK
 * "DR":x0(1byte) y0(1byte) x1(1byte) y2(1byte)--draw rectangle, top-left:x0,y0; right-bottom:x1,y1
 * "FR":x0(1byte) y0(1byte) x1(1byte) y2(1byte)--draw filled rectangle, top-left:x0,y0; right-bottom:x1,y1
 */

// that resetting the Arduino doesn't reset the LCD, so we
// can't assume that its in that state when a sketch starts (and the
// LiquidCrystal constructor is called).

//UART function

void DigoleSerialDisp::preprint(void) {
    //write((uint8_t)0);
    Print::print("TT");
}

/*----------Functions for Graphic LCD/OLED adapters only---------*/
void DigoleSerialDisp::drawBitmap(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int w, unsigned int h, const uint8_t *bitmap) {
    uint8_t i = 0;
    if ((w & 7) != 0)
        i = 1;
    Print::print("DIM");
    writePosition(x); //x;
    writePosition(y);
    writePosition(w);
    writePosition(h);
    for (int j = 0; j < h * ((w >> 3) + i); j++) {
        write(pgm_read_byte_near(bitmap + j));
//        delay(5);
    }
}

void DigoleSerialDisp::setRot90(void) {
    Print::print("SD1");
}

void DigoleSerialDisp::setRot180(void) {
    Print::print("SD2");
}

void DigoleSerialDisp::setRot270(void) {
    Print::print("SD3");
}

void DigoleSerialDisp::undoRotation(void) {
    Print::print("SD0");
}

void DigoleSerialDisp::setRotation(uint8_t d) {
    Print::print("SD");
    write(d);
}

void DigoleSerialDisp::setContrast(uint8_t c) {
    Print::print("CT");
    write(c);
}

void DigoleSerialDisp::drawBox(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int w, unsigned int h) {
    Print::print("FR");
    writePosition(x);
    writePosition(y);
    writePosition(x + w);
    writePosition(y + h);
}

void DigoleSerialDisp::drawCircle(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int r, uint8_t f) {
    Print::print("CC");
    writePosition(x);
    writePosition(y);
    writePosition(r);
    write(f);
}

void DigoleSerialDisp::drawDisc(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int r) {
    drawCircle(x, y, r, 1);
}

void DigoleSerialDisp::drawFrame(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int w, unsigned int h) {
    Print::print("DR");
    writePosition(x);
    writePosition(y);
    writePosition(x + w);
    writePosition(y + h);
}

void DigoleSerialDisp::drawPixel(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, uint8_t color) {
    Print::print("DP");
    writePosition(x);
    writePosition(y);
    write(color);
}

void DigoleSerialDisp::drawLine(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int x1, unsigned int y1) {
    Print::print("LN");
    writePosition(x);
    writePosition(y);
    writePosition(x1);
    writePosition(y1);
}

void DigoleSerialDisp::drawLineTo(unsigned int x, unsigned int y) {
    Print::print("LT");
    writePosition(x);
    writePosition(y);
}

void DigoleSerialDisp::drawHLine(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int w) {
    drawLine(x, y, x + w, y);
}

void DigoleSerialDisp::drawVLine(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int h) {
    drawLine(x, y, x, y + h);
}

void DigoleSerialDisp::nextTextLine(void) {
    write((uint8_t) 0);
    Print::print("TRT");
}

void DigoleSerialDisp::setFont(uint8_t font) {
    Print::print("SF");
    write(font);
}

void DigoleSerialDisp::setColor(uint8_t color) {
    Print::print("SC");
    write(color);
}

void DigoleSerialDisp::backLightOn(void) {
    Print::print("BL");
    write((uint8_t) 1);
}

void DigoleSerialDisp::backLightOff(void) {
    Print::print("BL");
    write((uint8_t) 0);
}

void DigoleSerialDisp::directCommand(uint8_t d) {
    Print::print("MCD");
    write(d);
}

void DigoleSerialDisp::directData(uint8_t d) {
    Print::print("MDT");
    write(d);
}

void DigoleSerialDisp::moveArea(unsigned int x0, unsigned int y0, unsigned int w, unsigned int h, char xoffset, char yoffset) {
    Print::print("MA");
    writePosition(x0);
    writePosition(y0);
    writePosition(w);
    writePosition(h);
    write(xoffset);
    write(yoffset);
}

void DigoleSerialDisp::uploadStartScreen(int lon, const unsigned char *data) {
     int j;
     uint8_t c;
    Print::print("SSS");
    write((uint8_t) (lon % 256));
    write((uint8_t) (lon / 256));
    delay(300);
    for (j = 0; j < lon;j++) {
        if((j%32)==0)
         delay(50);
         delay(_Comdelay);
        c=pgm_read_byte_near(data+j);
        write(c);
    }
}

void DigoleSerialDisp::uploadUserFont(int lon, const unsigned char *data, uint8_t sect) {
     uint8_t c;
    Print::print("SUF");
    write(sect);
    write((uint8_t) (lon % 256));
    write((uint8_t) (lon / 256));
    for (int j = 0; j < lon; j++) {
        if((j%32)==0)
         delay(50);
         delay(_Comdelay);
        c=pgm_read_byte_near(data+j);
        write(c);
    }
}
void DigoleSerialDisp::drawBitmap256(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int w, unsigned int h, const uint8_t *bitmap) {   //display 256 color image
    uint8_t i = 0;
    Print::print("EDIM1");
    writePosition(x); //x;
    writePosition(y);
    writePosition(w);
    writePosition(h);
    for (int j = 0; j < h * w; j++) {
        write(pgm_read_byte_near(bitmap + j));
//        delay(5);
    }
}
void DigoleSerialDisp::drawBitmap262K(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int w, unsigned int h, const uint8_t *bitmap) {  //display 256 color image
    uint8_t i = 0;
    Print::print("EDIM3");
    writePosition(x); //x;
    writePosition(y);
    writePosition(w);
    writePosition(h);
    for (int j = 0; (j < h * w *3); j++) {
        write(pgm_read_byte_near(bitmap + j));
//        delay(5);
    }
}
void DigoleSerialDisp::setTrueColor(uint8_t r, uint8_t g, uint8_t b) {  //Set true color
    uint8_t i = 0;
    Print::print("ESC");
    write(r); 
    write(g);
    write(b);
}
```

```
//DigoleSerial.h


//Digole Digital Solutions: www.digole.com
#ifndef DigoleSerialDisp_h
#define DigoleSerialDisp_h

#include <inttypes.h>
#include "Print.h"
#include <Wire.h>
#include "Arduino.h"

// Communication set up command
// Text function command
// Graph function command

#define Serial_UART 0;
#define Serial_I2C 1;
#define Serial_SPI 2;
#define _TEXT_ 0
#define _GRAPH_ 1

class DigoleSerialDisp : public Print {
public:
#if defined(_Digole_Serial_UART_)

DigoleSerialDisp(HardwareSerial *s, unsigned long baud) //UART set up
    {
        _mySerial = s;
        _Baud = baud;
        _Comdelay=2;
    }

    size_t write(uint8_t value) {
        _mySerial->write(value);
        return 1; // assume sucess
    }

    void begin(void) {
        _mySerial->begin(9600);
        _mySerial->print("SB");
        _mySerial->println(_Baud);
        delay(100);
        _mySerial->begin(_Baud);
    }
#endif
#if defined(_Digole_Serial_I2C_)

void begin(void) {
        _myWire->begin();
    }

    DigoleSerialDisp(TwoWire *s, uint8_t add) //U2C set up
    {
        _myWire = s;
        _I2Caddress = add;
        _Comdelay=6;
    }

    size_t write(uint8_t value) {
        _myWire->beginTransmission(_I2Caddress);
        _myWire->write(value);
        _myWire->endTransmission();
        return 1; // assume sucess
    }
#endif
#if defined(_Digole_Serial_SPI_)

void begin(void) {
    }

    DigoleSerialDisp(uint8_t pin_data, uint8_t pin_clock, uint8_t SS) //spi set up
    {
        _Clockpin = pin_clock;
        _Datapin = pin_data;
        _SSpin = SS;
        pinMode(_Clockpin, OUTPUT);
        pinMode(_Datapin, OUTPUT);
        pinMode(_SSpin, OUTPUT);
        digitalWrite(_SSpin, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(_Clockpin, LOW);
        digitalWrite(_Datapin, LOW);
        _Comdelay=6;
    }

    size_t write(uint8_t value) {
        digitalWrite(_SSpin, LOW);
        digitalWrite(_SSpin, LOW);
        digitalWrite(_SSpin, LOW);
        shiftOut(_Datapin, _Clockpin, MSBFIRST, value);
        digitalWrite(_SSpin, HIGH);
        return 1; // assume sucess
    }
#endif
    //    virtual size_t write(uint8_t);
    //    void begin(void);

        /*---------fucntions for Text and Graphic LCD adapters---------*/
    void writePosition(int p)
    {
    if(p>255)
    {
        write(255);
        p-=255;
    }
    write(p);
    }
    void disableCursor(void) {
        Print::print("CS0");
    }

    void enableCursor(void) {
        Print::print("CS1");
    }

    void drawStr(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, const char *s) {
        Print::print("TP");
    writePosition(x);
    writePosition(y);
        Print::print("TT");
        Print::println(s);
    }

    void setPrintPos(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, uint8_t graph = _TEXT_) {
        if (graph == _TEXT_) {
            Print::print("TP");
            writePosition(x);
            writePosition(y);
        } else {
            Print::print("GP");
            writePosition(x);
            writePosition(y);
        }
    }

    void clearScreen(void) {
        Print::print("CL");
    }

    void setLCDColRow(uint8_t col, uint8_t row) {
        Print::print("STCR");
        write(col);
        write(row);
        Print::print("\x80\xC0\x94\xD4");
    }

    void setI2CAddress(uint8_t add) {
        Print::print("SI2CA");
        write(add);
        _I2Caddress = add;
    }

    void displayConfig(uint8_t v) {
        Print::print("DC");
        write(v);
    }
    //print function

    size_t println(const __FlashStringHelper *v) {
        preprint();
        Print::println(v);
        Print::print("\x0dTRT");
    }

    size_t println(const String &v) {
        preprint();
        Print::println(v);
        Print::println("\x0dTRT");
    }

    size_t println(const char v[]) {
        preprint();
        Print::println(v);
        Print::println("\x0dTRT");
    }

    size_t println(char v) {
        preprint();
        Print::println(v);
        Print::println("\x0dTRT");
    }

    size_t println(unsigned char v, int base = DEC) {
        preprint();
        Print::println(v, base);
        Print::println("\x0dTRT");
    }

    size_t println(int v, int base = DEC) {
        preprint();
        Print::println(v, base);
        Print::println("\x0dTRT");
    }

    size_t println(unsigned int v, int base = DEC) {
        preprint();
        Print::println(v, base);
        Print::println("\x0dTRT");
    }

    size_t println(long v, int base = DEC) {
        preprint();
        Print::println(v, base);
        Print::println("\x0dTRT");
    }

    size_t println(unsigned long v, int base = DEC) {
        preprint();
        Print::println(v, base);
        Print::println("\x0dTRT");
    }

    size_t println(double v, int base = 2) {
        preprint();
        Print::println(v, base);
        Print::println("\x0dTRT");
    }

    size_t println(const Printable& v) {
        preprint();
        Print::println(v);
        Print::println("\x0dTRT");
    }

    size_t println(void) {
        Print::println("\x0dTRT");
    }

    size_t print(const __FlashStringHelper *v) {
        preprint();
        Print::println(v);
    }

    size_t print(const String &v) {
        preprint();
        Print::println(v);
    }

    size_t print(const char v[]) {
        preprint();
        Print::println(v);
    }

    size_t print(char v) {
        preprint();
        Print::println(v);
    }

    size_t print(unsigned char v, int base = DEC) {
        preprint();
        Print::println(v, base);
    }

    size_t print(int v, int base = DEC) {
        preprint();
        Print::println(v, base);
    }

    size_t print(unsigned int v, int base = DEC) {
        preprint();
        Print::println(v, base);
    }

    size_t print(long v, int base = DEC) {
        preprint();
        Print::println(v, base);
    }

    size_t print(unsigned long v, int base = DEC) {
        preprint();
        Print::println(v, base);
    }

    size_t print(double v, int base = 2) {
        preprint();
        Print::println(v, base);
    }

    size_t print(const Printable& v) {
        preprint();
        Print::println(v);
    }
    void preprint(void);
    /*----------Functions for Graphic LCD/OLED adapters only---------*/
    //the functions in this section compatible with u8glib
    void drawBitmap(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int w, unsigned int h, const uint8_t *bitmap);
    void drawBitmap256(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int w, unsigned int h, const uint8_t *bitmap);
    void drawBitmap262K(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int w, unsigned int h, const uint8_t *bitmap);
    void setTrueColor(uint8_t r, uint8_t g, uint8_t b);
    void setRot90(void);
    void setRot180(void);
    void setRot270(void);
    void undoRotation(void);
    void setRotation(uint8_t);
    void setContrast(uint8_t);
    void drawBox(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int w, unsigned int h);
    void drawCircle(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int r, uint8_t = 0);
    void drawDisc(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int r);
    void drawFrame(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int w, unsigned int h);
    void drawPixel(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, uint8_t = 1);
    void drawLine(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int x1, unsigned int y1);
    void drawLineTo(unsigned int x, unsigned int y);
    void drawHLine(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int w);
    void drawVLine(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int h);
    //-------------------------------
    //special functions for our adapters
    void setFont(uint8_t font); //set font, availale: 6,10,18,51,120,123, user font: 200-203
    void nextTextLine(void); //got to next text line, depending on the font size
    void setColor(uint8_t); //set color for graphic function
    void backLightOn(void); //Turn on back light
    void backLightOff(void); //Turn off back light
    void directCommand(uint8_t d); //send command to LCD drectly
    void directData(uint8_t d); //send data to LCD drectly
    void moveArea(unsigned int x0, unsigned int y0, unsigned int x1, unsigned int y1, char xoffset, char yoffset); //move a area of screen to another place

    void displayStartScreen(uint8_t m) {
        Print::print("DSS");
        write(m);
    } //display start screen

    void setMode(uint8_t m) {
        Print::print("DM");
        write(m);
    } //set display mode

    void setTextPosBack(void) {
        Print::print("ETB");
    } //set text position back to previous, only one back allowed

    void setTextPosOffset(char xoffset, char yoffset) {
        Print::print("ETO");
        write(xoffset);
        write(yoffset);
    }

    void setTextPosAbs(unsigned int x, unsigned int y) {
        Print::print("ETP");
        writePosition(x);
        writePosition(y);
    }
    void setLinePattern(uint8_t pattern) {
        Print::print("SLP");
        write(pattern);
     }
    void setLCDChip(uint8_t chip) {      //only for universal LCD adapter
        Print::print("SLCD");
        write(chip);
     }
    void uploadStartScreen(int lon, const unsigned char *data); //upload start screen
    void uploadUserFont(int lon, const unsigned char *data, uint8_t sect); //upload user font
    void digitalOutput(uint8_t x) {Print::print("DOUT");write(x);}
private:
    unsigned long _Baud;
    HardwareSerial *_mySerial;
    uint8_t _I2Caddress;
    TwoWire *_myWire;
    uint8_t _Clockpin;
    uint8_t _Datapin;
    uint8_t _SSpin;
    uint8_t _Comdelay;
};

#endif
```

And qMenuSystem has 4 files :

```
qMenuDisplay.cpp
#include "qMenuDisplay.h"
#include <Wire.h>

//DigoleSerialDisp _disp(8,9,10);
DigoleSerialDisp _disp(&Wire,'\x3C');

qMenuDisplay::qMenuDisplay()
{
}

qMenuDisplay::qMenuDisplay(DigoleSerialDisp disp)
{
  _disp=disp;
}

void qMenuDisplay::Start()
{
  _disp.clearScreen();
  _disp.setFont(18);
}

void qMenuDisplay::Finish()
{
}

void qMenuDisplay::Title(const char text[])
{
  _disp.setTextPosAbs(64-strlen(text)*9/2,11);
  _disp.print(text);
  _disp.drawHLine(0,14,128);
}

void qMenuDisplay::Item(int index,const char text[])
{
  _disp.setTextPosAbs(5,(index*14)+32);
  _disp.print(text);
}

void qMenuDisplay::Highlight(int index)
{
  _disp.setMode('~');
  _disp.drawBox(4,(index*14)+20,120,13);
}

void qMenuDisplay::MessageBox(const char text[])
{
  int textWidth=strlen(text)*9;
  int x=64-(textWidth/2);
  int y=32;

  _disp.setMode('&');
  _disp.setColor(0);
  _disp.drawBox(x-5,y-12,textWidth+9,21+3);
  _disp.setMode('~');
  _disp.setColor(1);
  _disp.drawFrame(x-3,y-10,textWidth+5,17+3);

  _disp.setTextPosAbs(x,y+5);
  _disp.print(text);
}
```

```
qMenuDisplay.h

#define _Digole_Serial_I2C_
#include <DigoleSerial.h>
#ifndef qMenuDisplay_h
#define qMenuDisplay_h

class qMenuDisplay
{
  public:
    qMenuDisplay(DigoleSerialDisp disp);
    qMenuDisplay();
    void Start();
    void Finish();
    void Title(const char text[]);
    void Item(int index,const char text[]);
    void Highlight(int index);
    void MessageBox(const char text[]);
  private:
//    char tempBuffer[32];
};




#endif
```

```
qMenuSystem.cpp

/////////////////////
// qMenuSystem
// version: 1.0
// 22.12.2013
// CLASS
/////////////////////
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>
#include "qMenuSystem.h"
#include "qMenuDisplay.h"

//DigoleSerialDisp disp(255,255,255);
//qMenuDisplay qmd;

qMenuSystem::qMenuSystem(DigoleSerialDisp disp)
{
  qmd=qMenuDisplay(disp);
  _selectedIndex=0;
  _itemCount=0;
  _firstVisible=1;
}

void qMenuSystem::InitMenu(const char ** page, int itemCount, int selectedIndex)
{
  CurrentMenu=page;
  _selectedIndex=selectedIndex;
  _itemCount=itemCount;
//  ProcessMenu(ACTION_NONE);
  ShowMenu();
}

int qMenuSystem::ProcessMenu(int action)
{
  if (action==ACTION_DOWN)
    _selectedIndex++;
  if (action==ACTION_UP)
    _selectedIndex--;

  if (_selectedIndex>_itemCount)
    _selectedIndex=1;
  if (_selectedIndex<1)
    _selectedIndex=_itemCount;

  if (action==ACTION_SELECT)
    return _selectedIndex;

  ShowMenu();

  return 0;
}

void qMenuSystem::ShowMenu()
{
  if (_selectedIndex>_firstVisible+2)
    _firstVisible=_selectedIndex-2;
  else if (_selectedIndex<_firstVisible)
    _firstVisible=_selectedIndex;

  qmd.Start();

  // display title
  strcpy_P(tempBuffer, (char*)pgm_read_word(&(CurrentMenu[0])));
  qmd.Title(tempBuffer);

  // display items
  int p = 3;
  if (p > (_itemCount-_firstVisible+1))
    p=_itemCount-_firstVisible+1;
  for (int i=0;i<p;i++)
  {
    strcpy_P(tempBuffer, (char*)pgm_read_word(&(CurrentMenu[i+_firstVisible])));
    qmd.Item(i,tempBuffer);
  }

  // display selection
  qmd.Highlight(_selectedIndex-_firstVisible);

  qmd.Finish();
}
```

```
qMenuSystem.h

/////////////////////
// qMenuSystem
// version: 1.0
// 22.12.2013
// HEADER
/////////////////////
#include "qMenuDisplay.h"

#ifndef qMenuSystem_h
#define qMenuSystem_h

#define ACTION_NONE    0
#define ACTION_UP      1
#define ACTION_DOWN    2
#define ACTION_SELECT  3
#define ACTION_BACK    4


class qMenuSystem
{
  public:
    qMenuSystem(DigoleSerialDisp disp);
    void InitMenu(const char ** page, int itemCount, int selectedIndex);
    int ProcessMenu(int action);
    void ShowMenu();
    void MessageBox(const char text[]) { qmd.MessageBox(text); };

    const char ** CurrentMenu;
  private:
    int _selectedIndex;
    int _itemCount;
    int _firstVisible;

    char tempBuffer[32];
    qMenuDisplay qmd;
};

#endif
```

Here is what it should show on the screen : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rjON_enuOGs

The example code that I'm using it this:

```
/*
======================================
qMenuSystem example #1
======================================

1. Connect OLED in SPI mode: DATA=D8, CLOCK=D9, SS=D10
2. Compile & upload
3. Open Serial monitor (Ctrl+Shift+M)
4. Use "q", "a", "s" to move across menu ("q" = up, "a" = down, "s" = select)

*/

#define _Digole_Serial_I2C_
#include <DigoleSerial.h>
#include <Wire.h>

#include <qMenuDisplay.h>
#include <qMenuSystem.h>

#include "TestMenu.h"

//DigoleSerialDisp mydisp=DigoleSerialDisp(8,9,10);
//DigoleSerialDisp _disp(&Wire,'\x3C');

//DigoleSerialDisp mydisp=DigoleSerialDisp _disp(&Wire,'\x3C');
//qMenuSystem menu=qMenuSystem(mydisp);
DigoleSerialDisp _mydisp(&Wire,'\x3C');
qMenuSystem menu(_mydisp);

void setup()
{
  //mydisp.begin();
  //mydisp.clearScreen(); //CLear screen
  menu.InitMenu(mnuRoot,cntRoot,1);
  //mydisp.write(0);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  int keycode=0;
  int clickedItem=0; 

  if (Serial.available()>0)
  {
    switch(Serial.read())
    {
      case 97:
        menu.ProcessMenu(ACTION_DOWN);
        break;
      case 113:
        menu.ProcessMenu(ACTION_UP);
        break;
      case 115:
        clickedItem=menu.ProcessMenu(ACTION_SELECT);
        break;
    }
  }

  if (clickedItem>0)
  {
    // Logic for Root menu
    if (menu.CurrentMenu==mnuRoot)
      switch (clickedItem)
      {
        case 1:
          menu.InitMenu(mnuSubmenu1,cntSubmenu1,1);
          break;
        case 2:
          menu.InitMenu(mnuSubmenu2,cntSubmenu2,1);
          break;
        case 3:
          menu.InitMenu(mnuSubmenu3,cntSubmenu3,1);
          break;
        case 4:
          menu.MessageBox("Some message!");
          break; 
      }
    // Logic for Submenu 1
    else if (menu.CurrentMenu==mnuSubmenu1)
      switch (clickedItem)
      {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 5:
          menu.MessageBox("Item clicked");
          break;
        case 6:
          menu.InitMenu(mnuRoot,cntRoot,1);
          break;
      }
    // Logic for Submenu 2
    else if (menu.CurrentMenu==mnuSubmenu2)
      switch (clickedItem)
      {
        case 1:
          menu.MessageBox("On");
          break;
        case 2:
          menu.MessageBox("Off");
          break;
        case 3:
          menu.InitMenu(mnuRoot,cntRoot,2);
          break;
      }
    // Logic for Submenu 3
    else if (menu.CurrentMenu==mnuSubmenu3)
      switch (clickedItem)
      {
        case 1:
          menu.MessageBox("Enabled");
          break;
        case 2:
          menu.MessageBox("Disabled");
          break;
        case 3:
          menu.InitMenu(mnuRoot,cntRoot,3);
          break;
      }

  } 
}
```

and with the bundled progmem part :

```
// required for "prog_char" and "PROGMEM"
#define _PROG_TYPES_COMPAT_
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>

// texts for menus

const char itmBack[] PROGMEM = "< Back";
const char itmOn[] PROGMEM = "On";
const char itmOff[] PROGMEM = "Off";
const char itmEnabled[] PROGMEM = "Enabled";
const char itmDisabled[] PROGMEM = "Disabled";

const char itmRoot[] PROGMEM = "Root menu";
const char itmSubmenu1[] PROGMEM = "Submenu 1";
const char itmSubmenu2[] PROGMEM = "Submenu 2";
const char itmSubmenu3[] PROGMEM = "Submenu 3";
const char itmMessageBox[] PROGMEM = "Message box";
const char itmItem1[] PROGMEM = "Item 1";
const char itmItem2[] PROGMEM = "Item 2";
const char itmItem3[] PROGMEM = "Item 3";
const char itmItem4[] PROGMEM = "Item 4";
const char itmItem5[] PROGMEM = "Item 5";

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// menus - first item is menu title and it does not count toward cnt

const char* mnuRoot[] = {
  itmRoot,
  itmSubmenu1,itmSubmenu2,itmSubmenu3,itmMessageBox};
const int cntRoot = 4;

const char* mnuSubmenu1[] = {
  itmSubmenu1,
  itmItem1,itmItem2,itmItem3,itmItem4,itmItem5,itmBack};
const int cntSubmenu1 = 6;

const char* mnuSubmenu2[] = {
  itmSubmenu2,
  itmOn,itmOff,itmBack};
const int cntSubmenu2 = 3;

const char* mnuSubmenu3[] = {
  itmSubmenu3,
  itmEnabled,itmDisabled,itmBack};
const int cntSubmenu3 = 3;
```

Can somebody please help me figuring out what's wrong that it doesn't show on the screen? (there are no errors on the code while compiling.)
Thank you so much for reading all the code I posted and for your time.

Comment: try changing the first include in qMenuDisplay.h

Comment: Thank you for reply, sorry but it's a little bit unclear. First  <include> in which file ? in the test code it's present straight from the start.